# Red5 Unable to Start Distribution

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, red5

I have installed subclipse, Ant, IvyDE, Red5 Plugin for eclipse, I added JAVA_HOME and JAVA_VERSION to environmental variables, I also added Java, and Ant to the windows path.

I am attempting to create a Red5 Distribution by using eclipse, opening Build.xml right clicking dist [default] in the outline window and running as and selecting Ant Builder.

Eclipse says that the build is Successful.  I first stop the Red5 Service, and then I attempt to run the build I create in eclipse it fails, below are the errors that display in the command prompt.

I was hoping someone else might have run into a similar issue before.

```
Starting Red5
Red5 root: C:/Users/Admin/workspace/temp/red5_server/dist
Configuation root: C:/Users/Admin/workspace/temp/red5_server/dist/conf
Setting temp directory to C:\Users\Admin\AppData\localLow
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        The import org.slf4j.bridge cannot be resolved
        The import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationC
ontext cannot be resolved
        SLF4JBridgeHandler cannot be resolved
        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type

        at org.red5.server.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:132)
        at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Any idea what might be causing it to error?

Comment: The lastest Red5 distributions are using Maven instead of ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. Don't understand yet, but seems things have changed since the videos, and contrary to what I initially found by searching. Contents of the dist directory are meant to be moved to a red5 distribution, but can be run by first changing into the dist directory, then entering, 
    "export RED5_HOME=`pwd`" and "./red5.sh", as suggested at the bottom of http://red5.org/wiki/Download#LatestDevelopmentSourceCode. (there are back-ticks around the pwd, but they got stripped out of this post.)

Not really an answer, but at least a clue. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the startup scripts, because the .bat worked in XP but the .sh didn't in Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem compiling with ant 1.7.1. Solved it using ant 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

We have seen issues when starting within eclipse, but does the same issue occur when you start from the dist directory from a command prompt / terminal? Two ways to resolve this are:

1. Launch from a command prompt / terminal

2. Use the red5 plugin